# Eclipse won't launch compiled .exe file

Tags: windows, eclipse, opengl, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Helios, CDT and mingw to make an opengl application. The executable it produces runs fine if run from a command line, but when I try to run it in Eclipse, nothing happens. Its a bit annoying having to switch to the command line every time to run it. I am using Windows 7, the same project in Eclipse on Ubuntu runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

this just happened to me - in a rush i installed mingw & msys - went to execute a hello world program and all that happened was the program built fine, then terminated. any program i ran would just terminate.

if you did the same thing i did, i forgot to add mingw & msys to the path - try editing your environment variables and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, didn't work. Maybe its because I'm using windows 7.